# Can't run most services. How do I fix that?

Tags: windows-7, windows, services

I had a mild suspicion that someone accessed my PC remotely, so I went into services and disabled some of them (like remote registry), just in case.

Unfortunately, I disabled something necessary, too. Now I can't install anything, and I can't access a lot of programs and services, like some of the Control Panels. The error message is always the same:

`The service cannot accept control messages at this time`.

But the services window I used to mess things up was still running (I hadn't closed it) and, fortunately, it still worked so I could do something! So I enabled and restarted most of services, but so far no change, still errors. Maybe I just need to reboot, but I'm afraid that if I reboot and nothing changes, then the services window will be gone and there will be no way to fix anything (as I can't launch services.msc anymore from the Control Panel - the same error shows up).

Would you please look at my services and let me know if there's anything obviously wrong. Or is it OK and I can reboot safely now?

[image: services window picture 1]
[image: services window picture 2]
[image: services window picture 3]
[image: services window picture 4]
[image: services window picture 5]

Comment: that mozilla maintenance service instance is highly suspect as its description is in Cyrillic and nothing else is (mine is im english).  Amongst your disabled services, I don't see anything critical, though I have Parental Controls set as Manual (not started). are you able to open a second window for services.msc? if so, you should be able to reopen it at will.

Comment: Just be patient, wait and try again. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms833805.aspx.

Comment: See the Black Viper Windows Services list, which shows various OS configurations. Check item by item. http://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/black-vipers-windows-10-service-configurations/

Comment: @FrankThomas:  The descriptions of “AVG Antivirus” and “Office Source Engine” are also Cyrillic,  and the last page’s worth have names (and descriptions, in about half of the case) that are Cyrillic

Comment: @FrankThomas, sorry for confusion, my system font was originally Cyrillic, I set it to English long ago, but strangely some words and descriptions remained unchanged. Unfortunately, I can't open a second services window, that was just me pasting a screenshot into MS Paint in a sloppy way, right on top of the previous screenshot.

Comment: "Office  Source Engine" (note the double space) instead of "Office Source Engine" - is that typo usually present in services.msc?

Comment: After some googling, that typo seems to be present on most modern-day Windows systems, although it doesn't appear to have been in Vista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix this by booting using the **Last Known Good Configuration** startup option:

1. Restart the computer.  Press `F8` repeatedly during startup to make Windows show the Advanced Startup menu.
2. Choose the Last Known Good Configuration boot option.  Let Windows boot.

Booting into the Last Known Good Configuration causes Windows to use a copy of the Windows Registry that was created the last time Windows successfully booted far enough to load a user's profile.  Because all of the changes you made to your service configuration are stored in the Registry, your unwanted changes will be discarded. Instead, the service state as it was the last time you successfully started your computer will be used.

**More Information:**

- [Last Known Good - Ask the Core Team](https://web.archive.org/web/20181127123218/https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2011/08/05/last-known-good/)